# iOS Alarm features in my app

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification, alarm

I am working on `iOS` application where I need to develop following Alarm standard features.

1. Set custom tone (or mute)
2. Set vibration (Yes/No)
3. Set snooze (Yes/No and snooze duration)

I have done research and found nothing helpful, first of all i want to know it is really possible? is there any restriction on these features from iOS? If it is possible please guide me so that I can explore.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do. You will have to post a LocalNotification for it. Have a look at this [post](http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/11/12/setting-a-reminder-using-uilocalnotification-in-ios-4-objective-c/).

To create vibration you can use AudioToolBox.framework.

`AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
 AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);`

Comment: above code will make vibration when application is in background?

Comment: No. Localnotifications can have default sound, custom sound or no sound at all. But iPhone will vibrate automatically if iPhone is set to vibrate.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //   Yes it is possible ,for alarm you have to use UILocalNotification class 
     For example :

    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    //---set the notification to go off in 10 seconds time---
    localNotification.fireDate =[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];
    //---the message to display for the alert---
    localNotification.alertBody = message.text; localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    //---uses the default sound---
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName; //---title for the button to display---
    localNotification.alertAction = @”View Details”;

    //---schedule the notification---
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

    //---display the notification now---
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];

    - (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@”Inside
    application:didReceiveLocalNotification:”
    message:notification.alertBody

    delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@”OK” otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];
    [alert release]; }

//application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method is also called when the
application is running and the local notification is fired.
```

Comment: thanx but my question was how to set custom tone of desired length, how to enable vibration during alarm and how to implement snooze function?